# How to access InstallDirRegKey in NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis

I can specify installation directory and registry value in NSIS like this:

```
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\CTVI"
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "Software\CTVI" "Install_Dir"
```

Now I can access `InstallDir` by using the notation `$INSTDIR` throughout the script. **How do I similarly access `InstallDirRegKey`?** Is there a similar notation as there exists for `InstallDir`? I tried `$INSTDIRREGKEY` but that is not. Now what I do is that I type `HKLM "Software\CTVI" "Install_Dir"` everytime I require it. But that is not so DRY :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `InstallDirRegKey` attribute is used, NSIS will look-up the specified registry entry at startup and if it finds a path there it will place that value in `$Instdir` before any of your code runs...

Comment: So you mean `$Instdir` can have either the value of `InstallDir` or `InstallDirRegKey`?